# Validation of number of images in a file for android

Tags: android, file, validation

I have a folder in which are stored images taken by the camera but the folder should not contain more than 8 images. How to do this?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? What are you trying to do?

Comment: i think folder should not contain more than 8 images right ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the absolute path of directory so that the method will check whether there r 8 files in folder or not.

```
 public boolean checkFilesInDirectory(String DirectoryPath)
 {     

    File f = new File(DirectoryPath);

    f.mkdirs();
    File[] files = f.listFiles();

    if (files.length == 8)
    return true;
    else
    return false;

 }
```